# Can't get data by MailChimp API 3.0 wrapper for Java Maleorang - 404 error

Tags: java, integration, mailchimp

I try use MailChimp API 3.0 wrapper for Java  - [Maleorang](https://github.com/Ecwid/maleorang).

I added dependency in pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ecwid</groupId>
                <artifactId>maleorang</artifactId>
                <version>${maleorang.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a code sample

```
  @Test
    public void RunMailChimp() throws Exception {
        MailchimpClient client = new MailchimpClient(MailChimpConstant.API_KEY);
        try {
            EditMemberMethod.CreateOrUpdate method = new EditMemberMethod.CreateOrUpdate(list_id, email);
            method.status = "subscribed";
            method.merge_fields = new MailchimpObject();
            method.merge_fields.mapping.put("FNAME", "***");
            method.merge_fields.mapping.put("LNAME", "***");

            MemberInfo member = client.execute(method);
            System.err.println("The user has been successfully subscribed: " + member);

   GetMembersMethod method = new GetMembersMethod(list_id);
    client.execute(method);

        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
    }
```

But I get error 404

```
INFO: Request: PUT https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/383444/members/8fb34d6f0c83fe617c0c45ce90b1a1096
Body: {"status":"subscribed","merge_fields":{"FNAME":"***","LNAME":"***"},"email_address":"****@mail.ru"}
окт 12, 2016 12:03:40 PM com.ecwid.maleorang.MailchimpClient execute
INFO: Response: 404 Not Found
Body: {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Resource Not Found","status":404,"detail":"The requested resource could not be found.","instance":""}
com.ecwid.maleorang.MailchimpException: API Error (404): The requested resource could not be found.
```

The links  https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/383444/members/8fb34d6f0c83fe617c0c45ce90b1a1096 , h_t_t_p_s:*/*/_us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/38341/members which generate method also don't open in browser (404 error)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need use list id from Lists->Settings->Unique id for list .Not list id from url.

Comment: Can you look at this similar question as well?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952518/add-subsciber-with-mobile-number-in-mailchimp3-0-list-using-java-wrapper